# How to set success for Team Services Command line step

Tags: ssis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Team Services (aka VSTS, aka Visual Studio Online, aka VSO), a Hosted build agent, and a command-line build step that executes an exe I don't own (devenv.exe) to build an .ispac file for SSIS package deployment. The process actually works, the ispac gets generated, copied, and published to the drop location, but the command-line build step shows a failure from a Team Services build standpoint. **I'd like to know how to tell the command line task everything is ok and show a successful build.**

Using the "Continue on error" flag causes the build to be "partially successful" and would hide actual failures from the build step.

Command-line step config:

```
Tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Arguments: $(build.sourcesdirectory)\MySolution.sln /build Development /project SSISPackages /Out $(build.sourcesdirectory)\SSISPackageBuild.log
```

Execution log:

```
2016-07-08T21:52:12.5511938Z Executing the following command-line. (workingFolder = C:\a\1\s)
2016-07-08T21:52:12.5521938Z "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" C:\a\1\s\MySolution.sln /build Development /project SSISPackages /Out C:\a\1\s\SSISPackageBuild.log
2016-07-08T21:52:12.5521938Z Error message highlight pattern: 
2016-07-08T21:52:12.5521938Z Warning message highlight pattern:
```

Comment: I dealt with a similar issue a long time ago but I can't remember all of the ins and outs.  Anyway, I believe if devenv.exe returns anything other than a 0 it will fail. I think that includes console output.  You can try changing the success value on the execute process task, running inside a script task, perhaps using a batch or file or something that then executes deven.exe quietly.  Do some research on SSIS execute process exit code, I think that will get you some ideas

Comment: You can create a powershell file or batch file to read the return value and return a different value to indicate success.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen. I've been investigating the PowerShell route to set the result.